# Is it possible to add new alphabets to unicode-math?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, unicode-math

In ordinary LaTeX, one can easily add new math alphabets by using `\DeclareMathAlphabet`. One is then able to use, say, `cmsy`, `eus`, and `rsfs` letters side-by-side. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a similar mechanism in `unicode-math`, or at the very least `\DeclareMathAlphabet` doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

**Question.** How can I set up my own math alphabets in `unicode-math`?

### Attempted workarounds

Since `unicode-math` has lots of math alphabets, one workaround might be to replace an unused alphabet with the desired one using `\setmathfont[range=...->...]`. This doesn't quite work right in my example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\scrollmode

\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr},StylisticSet=0]{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathtt->\mathcal}]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
\mathcal{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z} \\
\mathscr{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z} \\
\mathtt{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}
\end{array}
\]
```

I suspect the problem is that the codepoints of the calligraphic letters in Unicode are not contiguous.

Using `\mathversion` seems to work better:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\setmathfont[version=eucal]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\newcommand{\eucal}[1]{\mathchoice %
  {\mbox{\mathversion{eucal}$\displaystyle\mathscr{#1}$}} %
  {\mbox{\mathversion{eucal}$\mathscr{#1}$}} %
  {\mbox{\mathversion{eucal}$\scriptstyle\mathscr{#1}$}} %
  {\mbox{\mathversion{eucal}$\scriptscriptstyle\mathscr{#1}$}}}

\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
\mathcal{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z} \\
\mathscr{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z} \\
\eucal{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

But this feels very inefficient.

Comment: I've also been struggling with mixing multiple math fonts. Thanks to your workaround, I can now do `$\lambda x' \mathother{\lambda x'}$`, where `\mathother` is analogous to your `\eucal`. I have found no other way to do this and get all the symbols (Greek letters, primes, etc.) I need from all the fonts.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful! If you find any points that could be improved, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Actually `DeclareMathAlphabet` works fine, the problem is that the latin alphabet has been given mathcodes pointing at the math alphabet range in Unicode plane 1 (1Dxxx block) but the fonts are expecting the ASCII range.

unicode-math implements math alphabets by switching mathcodes (rather than changing the math fam) so the simplest thing to do is use `\mathup` to switch the mathcodes back to the ASCII range then use `\mathfrak` or `eufrak` or whatever to switch fam, as shown here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrsfs}{U}{rsfso}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\euler}{U}{euf}{m}{n}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}


\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{xits-math.otf}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cc}
1&\mathup{\mathrsfs{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}} \\
2&\mathcal{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z} \\
3&\mathscr{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z} \\
4&\mathup{\euler{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}}
\end{array}
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Is there a way to adjust the scaling as well, à la the `Scale` option in `fontspec`?

Comment: @ZhenLin I'll look over the weekend, a bit late now (I just watched `\tracingall` to reverse engineer the above and it's a bit late for that tonight:-)

Comment: I see! Thanks for the tremendous effort! I've hacked together something for scaling by modifying `\DeclareFontShape`.