# Redefining mathcal font

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a way to redefine the font that `\mathcal` uses in math mode. I would like any characters using the `\mathcal{}` function to be written in, for example, Asana Math font, and all other math text to be written in the default text. So far, I have:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

%%%Packages%%%

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

%\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\let\mathcal=\mathscr

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{p} = U(x,t)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

as my MWE.

Comment: Use the `range` options, as described in this duplicate: [Is it possible to add new alphabets to unicode-math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131866/is-it-possible-to-add-new-alphabets-to-unicode-math)

Comment: Have you looked into the `mathalpha` (aka `mathalfa`) package? It's designed to make it easy to switch the math alphabets behind `\mathcal`, `\mathscr`, and `\mathfrak`.

Comment: @Mico Yeah I have, but very little of it makes sense to me. I am incredibly novice with LaTeX and anything else like this, so it's tricky to work with these things unfortunately!

Comment: @HenriMenkeI can see how that could work, but I'm not sure what to put where! I tried \setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{Asana Math} but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

When setting a math font with `\setmathfont`, you can use the `range` option to specify which math alphabet you want to be changed, as long as you have defined a main math font. This works well with `unicode-math` fonts, but as said by others in the comments, in most cases the package `mathalpha` is really good to change `mathcal`, `mathscr`, `mathbb` and `mathfrak` fonts.

The following example uses the default alphabet used by `unicode-math` (Latin Modern Math) and then sets the `\mathscr` font to Asana Math.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{LatinModern-Math.otf}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}[range=scr]

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \\
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \\
\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
\mathcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
\mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: +1. The package `amsfonts` is loaded automatically by the `amsymb` package -- no need to load `amsfonts` package separately. Likewise, `fontspec` is loaded automatically by `unicode-math`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that! I removed the useless lines in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `\usepackage{eucal}`, this makes the `\mathcal` characters are in different font...

Comment: “\mathcal{} function to be written in, for example, Asana Math font”. That is not Asana Math.